# Conditional types and string literal + class union interaction

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, conditional-types

I've came across weird interaction within the types system while trying to properly type [`as` prop from emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled#as-prop).

```
import React, { Component, FC, PropsWithChildren } from "react";

// Possible types for `as` prop are tag name or component
type AsType =
  | keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
  | unknown


// Infered props based on `as`
type AsProps<T extends AsType> = {
  as?: T;
} & (T extends FC<infer FProps>
  ? FProps & { fc?: "fc" }
  : T extends new (...args: any) => Component<infer CProps>
  ? CProps & { cc?: "cc" }
  : T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
  ? JSX.IntrinsicElements[T] & { tag?: "tag" }
  : { non?: "non" });

const Box = <T extends AsType>(props: PropsWithChildren<AsProps<T>>) => null;

// Test components
class ClassComponent extends Component<{ CCProp: "foo" }> {}
const FunctionComponent: FC<{ FCProp: "foo" }> = () => null;

const Foo: FC = () => (
  <>
    <Box as={FunctionComponent} fc="fc" FCProp="foo" />
    <Box as={ClassComponent} cc="cc" CCProp="foo" />
    {/* Here types are inferred incorrectly.*/}
    {/* `tag` should be expected */}
    {/* `href` should show error that `true` is not assignable to `string` */}
    <Box as="a" tag="tag" href /> 
    <Box non="non" />
  </>
);
```

I'm linking a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-7b4g0) since the problem is hard to see without linting and autocomplete.

I'm using conditional types to expect correct props based on what is in the `as` prop and for string tags the type system straight up gives up.
If you specify the tag `as const` it works. If you don't, it's inferred as `string` and the conditional part of `AsProps` infers it as `non` type.
While messing around I found out that for some reason f.e. if you leave out `unknown` from `AsType` the tags work even without `as const`.

I can't figure out the correct solution.

Comment: It's important to include your [mcve] as text within the question itself, in addition to any external link (which is also helpful).  See [ask] for more information.

Comment: I've put the original code in the text of this question since link-only example code is not recommended and because the contents can change or disappear without any SO edit history, invalidating or changing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue you seem to be facing is that the compiler uses some heuristics to determine whether to take a value like `"a"` and infer its type to be the [string literal type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) `"a"`, or whether to widen it to `string`.  String literal values assigned to non-`const` variables or to function parameters tend to get widened to `string` by default.

As you've noticed, one way to prevent this widening is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#const-assertions).  The type of `"a" as const` will always be `"a"` and will not be widened to `string`.  This works in your case but puts the burden on the *caller* of `Box`, and you'd probably like this to happen without requiring people using `Box` to write `as const` anywhere.

Another way to prevent the widening is to have the value in a generic type inference site that has been [constrained](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a type containing `string` or a string literal.  (You can read more about the particular rules in [the pull request implementing this behavior, microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676).)  So if you have `declare function foo<T extends string>(x: T): void;` and call `foo("a")`, then `T` will be inferred as `"a"`.  *But* if you have `bar<T extends unknown>(x: T): void;` and call `bar("a")`, then `T` will be inferred as `string`.  A union type containing something assignable to `string` will work, so `T extends string | number` will still give you `"a"`.

Maybe now you're thinking "well, `keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | unknown` should be a union containing something assignable to `string`, since `keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements` looks like `"a" | "abbr" | "address" | "area" | "article" | ...` and each one of those is a string literal".  Well, as you've also noticed, `unknown` really messes that up.  You see, [`unknown` is TypeScript's top type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type).  A [top type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type) is a *universal supertype*; any type `X` will be a subtype of `unknown`.  And therefore, `X | unknown` will be equivalent to `unknown`.  The compiler aggressively simplifies any union with `unknown` to just `unknown`.  And you lose `"a" | "abbr" | ...`... which no longer hints the compiler to prevent the widening of `"a"` to `string`.

So, the workaround here is probably to give up on the explicit `unknown` and instead use something which is equivalent to it in terms of what types are assignable but which the compiler keeps as a union and does not aggressively simplify.  Before `unknown` was introduced, you'd have to use something like `{} | undefined | null` to mean "all possible types", and that still works:

```
type Unknown = {} | undefined | null; 

type AsType =
  | keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
  | Unknown
```

And then you get the behavior you want:

```
<Box as="a" tag="tag" href /> // error!
//                    ~~~~ <-- true is not a string
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#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-eAAIQghNeeOjArJmI6zSp3JhLBZHvYXB4-CE5BxWPleKpVNtlhpPj8nd27SQzHgtUdGa7fAySXw18iDvqVxHevOF4oOLw+F9uRDEggEDhjSOARt2p7UE4GDAKQj6XBQLLCngNCSn+AFAa83I7nuvj+OoYHwFQAEIfgGFYTy2w4l6vRwDi-aDhklg4FQkEwNBJCwU64jKpYsjqtQP5MDx-6ATsVG9LRA75MwjF3jeHFXOIQY8WGBACWAQloaJ2y9DgQQAFRwAAEpC8TNEkBS6KKkJQnA7i1FAwgYHwmjTHpQQRtRuD6WkdZZMwnAQL4njRLoRI6BgiJwG5HnUbpBmpJwwgSH5AVBXA-lmASDkpFwKDwKkPwOEgWTAPqEDwDewAlBUsTxBAaSnr8JRZNF2k0XRUk8SgGp1jxdYaolriiTsoTWdAACEbVHJ5M2zdRAB+i3zTRAC0K1FFARW2WVFXpXmJAlG1EmDs2PFtlp4lBNKHaqEAA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and link to the PR, it was very helpful. By replacing the `unknown` with `undefined` I got a bit closer to the solution, but there is still one big problem. I need to specify some type for `FC` generic argument otherwise I get Type 'FunctionComponent<{ FCProp: "foo"; }>' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>` when trying to use `FC` in `as` prop. If I set it to `FC<any>` in `AsType` again the string values become widened. [Here is updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-7b4g0)

Comment: This is essentially a new question, right?  The answer above explained what was happening and how to move past it; it makes sense that you might then hit further issues with your code, but I'm not inclined to rewrite the answer here.  If this becomes another question I'd say that type inference of a single parameter of a conditional type is complicated especially without official support for [non-inferential inference sites](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) and you might want to consider [overloads](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-drv0e) instead. Good luck!